# Security of Expansions files after downloading on device Android

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

I am searching on how to implement Expansion Files in android because of my apk size. Now problem is that Expension files stored on device storage so is that possible that after downloading expansion files on request anyone can copy these or transfer these files through usb and use these expansion files

Comment: The right solution depends, of course, on the nature of the data in your expansion file and on the kind of app. But you can always decrypt these data, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a JOBB tool for encapsulation and encryption http://developer.android.com/tools/help/jobb.html

Comment: yah i search on it but i want know that these obb files stored on device storage so is that possible these files can be copied after decryption??? i am asking about the security of these files

Comment: I'm sure that if someone really wanted to do it, they could, but I don't think it's trivial (i.e. I don't imagine that you can just find an unencrypted copy of the expansion file sitting somewhere where the user can grab it and copy it), as that would defeat the purpose. This is not for encrypting in transmission, it's for having it be encrypted on the device.